# Magento: Redirect User to 404 Page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Following problem: Under certain circumstances i want the user to be redirected to default page not found page of magento.

Therefore i declared an event observer with the following code.

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found',true);
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found',true);

        $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/default/cms_no_route');
        $url = rtrim(Mage::getUrl($pageId),'/');

        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
```

The redirect is working fine, but the given HTTP status code is 302 Found and not 404 Not Found.
Any hints what i did wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The official Magento way to do this:

```
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found');
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found');

    $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Cms_Helper_Page::XML_PATH_NO_ROUTE_PAGE);
    if (!Mage::helper('cms/page')->renderPage($this, $pageId)) {
        $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
    }
```

I copied this code from the `noRouteAction` function in  `/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php`.

I used it inside a controller of a custom module, and it works. 
Magento version: 1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
```

[`setRedirect()`[link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php#L93) accepts a second parameter for the response code; by default it is 302.

Comment: I suggest to call `$this->getResponse()->sendResponse(); exit;` after the `setRedirect()` call as a debug step. But `setRedirect($url, 404)` should work.

Comment: Doesn't work. HTTP Status Code 302 Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','404 Not Found',true);
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setHeader('Status','404 File not found',true);

            $pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/default/cms_no_route');
            $url = rtrim(Mage::getUrl($pageId),'/');

            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url, 404);
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->sendResponse(); exit;

Answer (score 1):

Do you `return` immediately after `setRedirect()`? If any output is sent after `setRedirect()` was called then redirect headers will eventually be ignored.

Remember that `exit` will not let the redirect headers sent either, unless you call `sendResponse()` before `exit` as @benmarks mentioned.